# CORS failure when uploading large files in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 service that receives large files. I have configured both the `RequestSizeLimit` and the `MultipartBodyLengthLimit` however I get a CORS error only for files over 30MB. Files under that upload without a problem. I am experiencing this locally with ISS express and in Azure App Services Windows host.

```
[RequestSizeLimit(525336576)]//501MB
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 524288000)]//500MB, which is already too high
[HttpPost("Video/{id:guid}")]
public IActionResult SetVideo(Guid id, IFormFile file)
{
   ...
}
```

Chrome error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44331/v1/Media/Video/a8a221ed-e111-42ad-aac7-d1fa380e81af' from origin 'https://localhost:44374' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image: Chrome Console]

Why is this manifesting as a CORS error? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide us the web.config file?

Comment: Whats the return code?

Comment: What shows for console/debug logs locally? It may be an exception is getting thrown there with 500 response and the CORS error is a red herring.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I was missing the IIS security settings in the web.config. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is probably a 413.13, the browser tends to mask them as a CORS issue, I had myself a bad time last month with this same error.

The case is: Your .Net application is prepared to receive larger files, but you need to tell IIS to accept them as you are using IIS as your webserver.

To do so, inside your `web.config` file inside the `<system.webServer>` tag add the following lines

```
 <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <!-- Configures IIS to accept files up to 500MB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you sir.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but I want to keep the limit on the content length, so I would like to understand, why this limit results in a CORS issue?

When I keep the request below the limit, the response includes an 'access-control-allow-origin' header, but when the size of the request is above the limit, there is no such origin-header....instead I get a CORS-issue when trying to check if I get a 413-response. Why is that? (I hoped, I could just check for a 413-response and give a nice message to the end user)